# Anchoring an arrow to a shape in Sketch

Tags: flowchart, sketchapp

I know this is quite a basic question, but I've been unable to find an answer to it anywhere.

Is there a way to anchor an arrow (or line) a particular shape so that when the shape moves it drags the arrow/line along?

Right now if I move the shape, it just disconnects from the arrow

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

1. Grouping the arrow with your shape
2. Lock the arrow
3. Move the groupe instead of the layer alone

[image]